# Initialization on demand for multiple static variables without static nested classes?

Tags: java, lazy-loading, lazy-evaluation, lazy-initialization, static-initialization

I want to have a class with multiple static variables that will only be initialized on demand.

```
public class Messages {
    public static final String message1 = init1();
    public static final String message2 = init2();
}
```

So when somewhere in the code I reference `Messages.message1` I want only `init1()` to be called. If later I access  `Messages.message2` then only at that time should `init2()` be called.

I know it is possible to do this with the [Initialization-on-demand holder idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization-on-demand_holder_idiom), but this is cumbersome if you have lots of fields.

Is there another way?

Comment: Similar to what you linked, instead of referencing a field, invoke a method. The method will return (and cache) the initialized value.

Comment: enum singleton may help?

Answer (score 2):

Most common way for lazy initialization is initialization in getter method:

```
public class Messages {
    private static String message1;
    public static String getMessage1() {
        if (message1 == null)
            message1 = init1();
        return message1;
    }
}
```

If you want exactly `public final static` fields then there is no way to achieve separate initialization for them in Java. All class members are initialized together.